# Testing a GeoServer "Scrolling" performance

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, performance

I'm looking for a way to test the responsiveness of various layers when scrolling around the map. So after a layer is loaded and the user is moving around the map looking a specific area or whatever.

We are currently using GeoServer and OpenLayers for the application and are looking into ways to increase the performance of the application. I've messed around with Jmeter but it seems to be just testing get requests and not necessarily the users experience when using the application. I've also tried using the developer tools in Chrome and recording the performance while doing a preset scrolling/zooming pattern. This seem to work pretty well but is obviously not going to be very precise.

So essentially are there any tools/techniques that I can use for testing responsiveness of a layer when scrolling around the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up displaying the layers in a Chrome and opening the inspect window. In the network tab I made sure all logs were clear. From there I did a consistent set of movements such as zooming and scrolling. I repeated those exact movement several times to get an average. From there I found IMG raster files have the best performance, follow by TIFF, then JPG2K.